# Twitter prevents script blocking

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script, firefox-extensions, twitter, ublock

I have come across a weird issue. When I have [UBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) in [Pale Moon](http://palemoon.org/) turned on to block all scripts (including inline-scripts), the [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) webpage somehow shows the following nasty behaviour:

1. It does not show the context-menu on right-click (but double-right-click brings it up).
2. A lot of standard keys do not work, including Up/Down/PgUp/PgDn and F5 and Backspace and Alt+Left/Right/Home. Ctrl+W does not close the tab, and Ctrl+T does not bring up a new tab (but Ctrl+Tab works).

I have confirmed that it has to do with blocking Twitter scripts, because I have two other addons (one being [AdBlock Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-lite-firefox/)) that block downloading of scripts via an NsIContentPolicy, both of which claim to successfully block:

- <sub>https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.177cca4ba1304414e6dda19ae6692dad849e9e53.js</sub>

But do not block:

- <sub>https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/bundle/timeline.d1b4f75f296f886e49e746b3d6acd832e55f9884.js</sub>
- <sub>https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/bundle/boot.edfcb53dfdd7dfa0066212c8f7b4e193d97e4dca.js</sub>

I suspect UBlock Origin also fails to block some scripts, which hijack the mouse and certain keyboard shortcuts. When all three addons are turned off for Twitter, the above nasty behaviour vanishes.

I even have a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script set to `@run-at document-start` and `stopImmediatePropagation` on any keydown event, yet it fails to prevent the keyboard hijacking.

**My questions**

1. I see that the first JS file that is apparently blocked is linked from a `<script>` tag, and not just from a `<link>` tag. So I'm guessing that the NsIContentPolicy fails for `<link>` tags (especially with the attribute `rel='preload'`?). I would be grateful if anyone can explain what is going on.
2. Is there a way I can have a 100% guarantee of blocking all scripts from running unless I white-list them on a case-by-case basis?

The [mobile version of Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/) works fine and does not hijack the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I don't see the behavior you are describing. If I block all inline-script + 1st-party and 3rd-party scripts, all scripts are blocked, the right-click contextual menu is shown properly, page dn/up work fine. Also, _"I suspect"_ is completely unhelpful -- you do not have to "suspect", just use the dev console to confirm that all scripts are blocked.

Comment: @rhill: I'd appreciate if you tell me how to check properly. In the Javascript profiler I see nothing from Twitter running, but if so, how can the keys and mouse be hijacked? Can you tell me how the `<link rel='preload'>` tag is handled? How do I capture those requests being made?

Comment: @rhill: When I commented previously, I did not know that the console had an option to disable Javascript. Indeed doing so blocks all scripts, and so does my GM script. So there is clearly something wrong with UBlock Origin. It seems that it successfully blocks inline scripts on other websites, since my GM-injected event-listener is not triggered on them unlike on the Twitter webpage, and the console logs CSP violations. I think my method is better than using a CSP, as it should be impossible for anything except another extension to inject an event-listener before mine. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @rhill: By the way, are you the developer of UBlock Origin? On the Twitter webpage it generates the following error when I click on the page: `TypeError: elem.matches is not a function @ chrome://ublock0/content/js/scriptlets/load-large-media-interactive.js:160`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I had some time to come back to this. I used a GreaseMonkey script to inject an event-listener for `beforescriptexecute` to prevent all scripts from loading, and found that UBlock Origin (1.9.6) was failing to block the inline scripts on the Twitter webpage from running. So I have essentially answered my own question:

1. The problem was with UBlock Origin and not at all with the `<link rel="preload" ...>` tags.
2. Using this GM script I can easily block all scripts and specifically white-list any that I wish.